# Search two columns in Excel for duplicates in different rows then only count one row when summing values in a separate column

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, multiple-columns

I am new to the Stackoverflow and I would greatly appreciate anyone's help here as I've racking my brain trying to figure it out if I need a macro or not. Essentially I'd like to match columns A and B to find a duplicate in either direction then only sum the first instance of the match. So I would only sum 10+9+8+7.

```
**A**   **B**   **Value**
```

**1**   345155  345670  $10

**2**   345345      $9

**3**   345346      $8

**4**   345672      $7

**5**   345670  345155  $10

Answer (score 0):

create a new column and use the below formula

```
=IF((COUNTIF(A$1:A5,A6)+COUNTIF(B$1:B5,A6)+COUNTIF(A$1:A5,B6)+COUNTIF(B$1:B5,B6))>0,0,C6)
```

take sum of this new column

this would ignore the value to be added, if a value in any columns (A or B) is repeated in any of the columns (A or B)

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Place this formula in a separate column. Say, column E

`=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,B2:B$7,0)),"","Add")`

Then this formula anywhere you want: `=SUMIF(E1:E7,"Add",C1:C7)`

This assumes a match on one side is *always* a match on the other side. If you need to ensure both sides match, change the first formula to this:

`=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,B2:B$7,0)),ISNUMBER(MATCH(B1,A2:A$7,0))),"","Add")`